# python "WORKON_HOME" not showing virtual environments in helm

Tags: spacemacs, python, virtualenv

I've check to see my `WORKON_HOME` env is set to where I want it at `/home/user/anaconda3/envs` but in helm the only option i get is `..` if I select that option Emacs thinks my virtual environment is `anaconda3`.

If I use `M-x pyvenv-activate` I can navigate to my virtual environment and everything is fine. I just can't seem to get `pyvenv-workon` to point to my environment

For refence I'm using spacemacs with
`(setenv "WORKON_HOME" "/home/user/anaconda3/envs")`
in my `user-init` section and verified it is set with `M-x getenv WORKON_HOME`

Comment: I know this is an old question but have you figured out what the solution was?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself with the same problem. The problem was that I started from a completely new miniconda3 install and although I had created a virtual environment, it was not initialized yet. So after installing a module `pvyenv-workon` worked as expected.

So, in your terminal, just `create` an environment, `activate` it and install a module e.g. `conda install wheel`